# when you select the option it will change the other text box angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

i created a `formarray` that when the user select a specific data it will trigger the other text box but different data. how will you do that?

> .TS

```
this.deliveryReceiptForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  displayArray : this.formBuilder.array([this.createList()])
})

createList(): FormGroup {
return this.formBuilder.group({
  itemId : ['', Validators.required],
  itemDescription : ['', Validators.required]
 })
}

update(ctrl){
 //i dont know what to code
 }
}
```

> .HTML

```
 <td>
  <mat-select style="width:200px" class="form-control"
   (selectionChange)="selectedItemCode($event)" 
    formControlName="itemId" (change)="update($event.target)"> //change is this correct?
      <mat-option *ngFor="let items of propertyItem"  
       [value]="items.id">
       {{items.propertyNo}}
      </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
 </td>

 <td>
  <input style="width:300px" class="form-control" 
  type="text"formControlName="itemDescription">                       
 </td>
```

so this is what i wanted to do when you select the propertyitem it will populate the itemdescription but different data

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you don't need to listen to the change in DOM. You already got the Input inside your FormBuilder, you can subscribe to changes there.

I'm not really sure what you want to archive, but here is an example of how to update the second field on value change: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4fth2e?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqJry.png here the example of the table i when i select it will get the other column